# how ElectronJS Check Browser installed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, io

I wonder if there's a way **ElectronJS** or perhaps in **NodeJS** 
for Detecting All Softwares (Browsers installed) do i have installed?

I ended up with child_process and manually pipeout the wmic output from CSV.
Is there any other solutions?